# I have ClutterGdk, how to install ClutterGtk?

Tags: gtk, clutter

I'm curious about ClutterGtk, and want to see if GtkClutterEmbed could fit in my current task. But I have ClutterG**d**k in GI repository, and `sudo apt-get install clutter-gtk` isn't going to work.

I've found some resource around, but before trying them, I'd like to know if I'm missing the proper way to install.

*edit*

after suggestion by @jku, I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
```

but I get

```
...
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 is already the newest version
```

so, since I cannot spot the related typelib in /usr/lib/girepository-1.0, what's going on ? Should I attempt to build the typelib by myself ?

Comment: Can you explain why installing Clutter-GTK isn't going to work?

Comment: I do `$ sudo apt-get install Clutter-GTK` (well, I use tried all lower case as well) and I get `...E: Unable to locate package Clutter-GTK`

Comment: Nothing guarantees that the package would be called exactly that. In fact on Debian or Ubuntu it's likely not correct. Use your package managers search to find the correct package (e.g. `apt-cache search clutter-gtk` might help).

Comment: @jku: thanks, I'll update the question...

Comment: Did you install `libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev` too?

Comment: @andlabs: no, I was attempting to keep things simple as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typelib files for GObject introspection on Debian are in the `gir1.2-*` packages.

Clutter-GTK's typelib file is provided by the `gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0` package.

Comment: thanks, installed. I got two message I don't understand (`gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 is already the newest version.
gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 set to manually installed.
`) and now GtkClutter is available !